# Bones move out of mesh when changing from Edit mode to Object mode

Tags: bones, pose-mode, object-mode

I imported a mesh to play around with it and I tried to animate it so it put bones in it. When I am in editor mode everything looks right but when I change the mode the bones of the torso are moving out of the mesh:[image]

I was able to find something in the Internet but it didn't work.
Thank you!

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Yeah, sure: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5158" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5158/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bit messed up your armature in *Pose* mode, so you need to switch back to *Pose* mode, select all your bones, then <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> (reset scale, rotation and location)

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! How can I avoid this in the future?

Comment: if you don't go in Pose mode, it won't happen. Once you go in Pose mode, you can move your bones as much as you want, record the new poses with keyframes, go back to the initial pose with alt r s g, etc... you should learn all this with animation tutorials